# Why my case class saved as $classname into mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb, scala

I have a case class and a trait like this.

```
trait A {
    val _id: Option[A] = None 
    val d: Option[List[D]] = None
    val id: Option[String] = None
}

object A {
  def apply(className: String): Element = Class.forName(className: String).asInstanceOf[A]
  def unapply(element: A): Option[String] = Option(this.getClass.getName) 
}

case class B extends A (
    value1: String, value2: A, sub: Option[TypeY] = None
)

object B {

  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

  implicit val AFormatter: Format[A] = Json.format[A]

  implicit val BFormatter: Format[B] = Json.format[B] 

  implicit val Breads:Reads[B] = Json.reads[B]

  implicit  val BWrites = Json.writes[B]

}
```

while inserting a data corresponding to case class B, the value2 is being saved as "$A" : "abc.xyz.data", where "A" is the trait name and "abc.xyz.data" is the package name. is this because of my apply and unapply methods? How to solve this?

**Edit : DB saving code**

I'm using ReactiveMongo library to save data to DB.

```
def collB : JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("B")

def indbNewB(b: B) = {

  collB.insert(B)

}
```

Comment: Which lib are you using? What have you already tried?

Comment: I think the problem is that you trying to serialize a trait. And it doesn't matter what is the value of `value2`, all information the serializer has to work with is that it's has type `A`.

Comment: @pedrofurla: If I dont add json serialization / de-serialization, then I get "trait A doesnt have apply, unapply implemented" error.

Comment: You either need another design or write you own hand-written formatter. Which is not hard at all.

Comment: hand-written formatter for the trait?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not correctly serializing to JSON / string the case class `A`.

If you could post more details (such as the code actually storing data to DB), I will update my answer.